# How to enable/disable a certain field(s) base on input from drop-down menu?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

**Dropdown Menu** 
id = payment_method

- paid by reciever
- charge through invoices

**Dropdown Menu** 
id = shipping_carrier

- Fedex
- DHL

**Input Field** 
id = shipping_number __________________

**Goal:**

if user select **charge through invoices**

- disable shipping_carrier
- set Fedex as default
- hide() my shipping number input

Else,

- enable the shipping_carrier
- enable shipping number input (required)

Code

```
<script>
  var logistic = function () {
    if ($( "#payment_method option:selected" ).text("Charge through invoices")) {
        $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', false);

    else {
        $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  };
  $(logistic);
  $("#paid_by_reciever").change(logistic);



</script>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be more helpful than a description. May be we should give a purely descriptive answer :)

Comment: This is my first post in stackoverflow. I guess I should follow your suggestion (jsfiddle). Thank for the tip @PeterKA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
$("#payment_method").change(function() {
  console.log($("#payment_method option:selected").val());
  if ($("#payment_method option:selected").val() == 2) {
    $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#shipping_carrier').val(1);
    $('#shipping_number').hide();
  } else {
    $('#shipping_carrier').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#shipping_number').show();
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
 Payment method: <br />
 <select id="payment_method" name="payment_method">
  <option value="1">paid by reciever</option>
  <option value="2">charge through invoices</option>
 </select>
</label>

<label>
 Shipping Carrier
 <select id="shipping_carrier" name="shipping_carrier">
  <option value="1">Fedex</option>
  <option value="2">DHL</option>
 </select><br />

</label>

<label>
 Shipping number<br />
  <input type="text" name="shipping_number" id="shipping_number" value="" />
</label>
```

Comment: Not entirely true. `$(logistic)` and `.change(logistic)` are valid.

Comment: @lolka_bolka : Thank you. You're awesome. :) This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @lolka_bolka : Your code, work great. Now, what if I want to trigger the same functions base on an old input(s) in one of my Edit form, do you have any suggestions ? I hope you don't mind point me to the right direction.